# Mongoose not saving document, getting "MongoClient must be connected" error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I am trying to connect to MongoDb using mongoose. Here is the code I am using to connect:

controller.js

```
const conn = mongoose.createConnection(db, {
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useUnifiedTopology: true
        })

        conn.once('open', () => {
            console.log(`${req.body.db} DB connected`)
            const model = conn.model(`item`, Item, req.body.collection)

            let stuff = uploadToS3(req.files)
            stuff.then(paths => {
                const newItem = new model({
                    nameOfItem: req.body.name,
                    pictures: paths,
                    description: req.body.description,
                    year: req.body.year,
                    favorite: req.body.favorite
                })

                //save data to MongoDB
                newItem.save()
                    .then(item => {
                        console.log(item)
                        res.json(item)
                    })
                    .catch(err => console.log(err))
                conn.close()
            })
        })
```

I don't think this matters, but I will state it anyway. I am using a single schema for several different databases and collections. Here is the schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const pictureSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    path: String
})
const itemSchema = new Schema({
    nameOfItem: { type: String, required: true },
    pictures: [pictureSchema],
    description: String,
    year: String,
    favorite: {type: Boolean, default: false}
})

module.exports = itemSchema
```

And I am pulling the schema into the controller using this:

```
const Item = require('../models/item.model')
```

Here is the output:

```
bottles DB connected
{
  fieldname: 'photos',
  originalname: 'DSCN5104.JPG',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
  destination: 'uploads/',
  filename: '1c17e793b340658f14bcc92c98444d95',
  path: 'uploads\\1c17e793b340658f14bcc92c98444d95',
  size: 2107729
}

MongoNotConnectedError: MongoClient must be connected to perform this operation
    at getTopology (C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\Project\server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:367:11)
    at Collection.insertOne (C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\Project\server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\collection.js:150:82)
    at NativeCollection.<computed> [as insertOne] (C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\Project\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\collection.js:200:33)
    at model.Model.$__handleSave (C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\\Project\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:294:33)
    at model.Model.$__save (C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\Project\server\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:374:8)
    at C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\Project\server\node_modules\kareem\index.js:281:16
    at C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\Project\server\node_modules\kareem\index.js:78:15
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11)
bottles DB closed
```

What confuses me is that it says that it is connected and giving me that error at the same time. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those that run into this post, I figured it out. I had `conn.close()` in the wrong area. It turns out that the place that I had it was outside and right after an async function, so it was being called immediately after calling the function but before the function resolved. I moved it into this function call:

```
newItem.save()
    .then(item => {
        console.log(item)
        res.json(item)
        conn.close()
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
```